# i was wondering how to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to0} x\sum 1/n$

Tags: limits, summation

I was wondering how to evaluate 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n$$

**Edit**

so that it's clear I mean 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x*\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n$$ 
witch is equvalent to 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac x n$$

Comment: If the quantity $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$ doesn't converge, how do you talk about this quantity?

Comment: not defined, may be you meant that $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{1}{n}$ !

Comment: To reinforce what's been said so far, right now this is (approximately) equivalent to asking 'what's three divided by blue?' - the expression you've written, while it's syntactically valid, is semantic nonsense because one of the quantities involved is undefined. There are various ways of giving it meaning (as suggested in another comment, you could look for the limit of $x\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{x^{-1}}\frac1n$) but without choosing one there is no meaningful answer (and the answer you get can depend on which one you choose).

Comment: What you've written makes no sense. Could you please explain in words what you are trying to understand and your thought process behind the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \left( x \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n \right),$ then that is $\lim\limits_{x\to0} (x\cdot\infty) = \lim\limits_{x\to0} \infty = \infty. $

But if you mean $\displaystyle \left( \lim_{x\to0} x \right) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n,$ then that is $0\cdot\infty,$ which in some contexts one should interpret as $0.$

However, remember also that if two expressions $A$ and $B$ both vary as functions of $x$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0} A = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0} B = \infty,$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to0} (AB)$ may be some particular number, such as (for example) $8,$ depending on which functions $A$ and $B$ are.

Comment: yea the first one that's what I meant, I should have been more clear I corrected it in the edit. Thank You

Comment: The limit is $\infty$ only if you approach zero from the right. If you approach zero from the left, the limit is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\right)\lim_{x\to 0}x$$
since the series does not depend on $x$. Hence, the above expression is undefined, as 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$$
is divergent.

Comment: Cool thanks, I thought that because x multiplied the summation it would be something else like 0.

Comment: Pulling $\infty$ out is not valid.